# Has a sitting US president ever revealed highly classified information?

Tags: united-states, president, classified-information

Has any US president, during their tenure in office, accidentally told the public or the press secret or top secret information?

**Bonus question:** Is there an official procedure for if this were to happen?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes, Several times in the lead up to the war with Iraq, George W Bush revealed information from his [PDB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/President%27s_Daily_Brief) that was not only secret but his revealing of the information put some of our agents at risk of exposure.

However the president is the ultimate classification authority, meaning that the person holding the office of POTUS, can classify or declassify government documents as the needs of the country dictate.  Unlike when aides and staffers accidentally/incidentally reveal classified\secret information  there is no reporting of the breach required.

Comment: Isn't there a specific procedure that POTUS needs to follow in order to declassify documents? The way I see it, the President cannot *intentionally* leak information (because he can declassify anything), but he might *accidentally* do so (i.e. before completing the legally required procedure). Am I right?

Comment: Can you provide examples of Bush leaking Iraq-related info that put agents in danger?

Comment: @A.Darwin - No this was discussed during the Valerie Plame issue.  The president has full executive authority to share what ever information he feels he has the need to share regardless of classification.  Scooter Libby confirmed a GWB leak. Despite the fact that GWB had shared the name previously with a media source the information was not declassified.  That is why he went to jail and nothing happened with GWB.

Comment: @AndrewGrimm - The yellow cake in Uganda was out of a PDB and was classified secret when it was released. The Bush administration then had to combat a leak from the husband of CIA Agent that had been sent to investigate.  Again still classified secret.  This led to the outing of a CIA Agent. The document was only semi declassified during the inquiry into why there were no WMD found, and the leaks about the issue.

Comment: Could Congress change the law to make it a crime for the president to leak classified information without going through an appropriate process first? That is would it require a constitutional amendment?

Comment: @Lembik - Well the president is in charge of the justice department and enforcing the laws.  So even if congress enacted that law, no president is going to enforce it on themselves.  It could already be prosecuted for impeachment under high crimes and misdemeanors if congress decided that the breach was bad enough.

Comment: @DrunkenSanta9035768 When you say the president is in charge of enforcing laws, that isn't literally true is it? I mean the president doesn't decide who will be prosecuted for what crime.

Comment: @Lembik - That is **LITERALLY** the job of the president.  Every action the president does is technically supposed to be in furtherance of enforcing existing laws.  In most cases the president delegates those decisions, but if you think that the president did not have a say in the decision not to charge Hillary, or the decision to charge Scooter Libby, well I have a great piece of beach front property in your price range id like to interest you in...

Comment: @DrunkenSanta9035768 I am not so sure. I mean in terms of the law not in terms of secret and undisclosed influence.  See e.g. http://fortune.com/2016/10/10/donald-trump-special-prosecutor-hillary-clinton/  and e.g.  "Under the laws and Justice Department regulations governing federal prosecution, a President Trump would not have legal authority to direct the Attorney General to appoint a special prosecutor to 'look into' Hillary Clinton's email situation or the Clinton Foundation or anything else. That's not within a President's power."

Comment: But the president could direct the AG to do that themselves.

Comment: @DrunkenSanta9035768 No that's the entire point of my comment. The president, apparently, cannot simply instruct the AG to do things by law.  He could fire the AG and then try to hire one that already agreed to his policy of course.

Comment: @Lembik - That is effectively the same thing. The laws that prevent the directing are also not protected constitutional rights or requirements.  So again the only repercussion would happen in congress through impeachment

Comment: @DrunkenSanta9035768 The difference is that the AG can legally refuse. So it's not like when a general orders his men who can be court-marshalled for refusing orders.

Comment: @lembik - Actually a general can refuse too.  McArthur did in WWII and Patton.just straight out disobeyed them.

Comment: @DrunkenSanta9035768 I don't think a general can legally refuse a legal order. Amusingly, the president elect doesn't have any protection at all so he has a few days to get himself arrested.

Comment: @Lembik - the thing is a court marshal is handled by military officers who are more likely to back the general trying to avoid being used for political purposes than the president.  Effectively it is exactly the same as the AG.

Comment: @SoylentGray your specific examples would greatly strengthen your answer if they were included with appropriate citations

Comment: @ColinZwanziger - Like the one included in the answer as an example... yeah done that toll along little boy.

Answer (score 3):

Jimmy Carter in an open forum after he killed the B1 bomber told the public we were developing stealth aircraft years before we had them.He was trying to win an election and broke the news to establish his defense creds.

Comment: Your answer would greatly improve if you add a source/reference for that :-)